# Only individually saved products are shown

Tags: magento2

in Magento 2 I have a rare problem. If I select some products and me for example change the status to Active, this is not done. But If I enter one of these products (child) and I only click **save** then yes is done and it's shown on the website.
Thanks

Comment: Any error on log file or console while you are doing this one?

Comment: No, no error in log or report